# Analog of raf.seek(pos)

Tags: java, kotlin, randomaccessfile

I wanna find analog of `raf.seek(pos)` method from java.
Need to find page by number in text file (book's page).

```
val raf = RandomAccessFile(file, "r")
raf.seek(pageNumber * PAGE_SIZE)
raf.read(bytePage)
```

I don't like my version. It's too java oriented. Wanna find other way. W/o byte array maybe.

Comment: I didn't get your requirement, could you please elaborate? What does *I don't like my version. It's too javish.* mean?

Comment: your requirement is not clear , can you explain it with use case ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when you look at the android side of things, you will find that [RandomAccessFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/RandomAccessFile) is **in deed** coming out of the java standard libraries.

In other words: there is no specific "kotlin'ized" version of that class.

Thus the answer is: up to now, you have to go with your "java'ish" looking code.